# How does STAN computation time scale with number of iterations?

Tags: mcmc, stan

I'm using MCMC to fit a bayesian mixed model. I have not a particular strong background in coding/computer science and I was wondering about something which seems very weird to me.

When I set the number of iterations for my MCMC sampling through STAN to 100 the sampling is complete in like 20" , when I set it to 1000, it takes like an hour to get to 100.

Is it something about the sampling method or what?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with how adaptation works.  See the manual.